# Rails routes: redirect a wild card route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a website built in Ruby on Rails and a blog built in WordPress.  The url for the main site will be `example.com` and the url for the blog is `blog.example.com`.  Because of the way search engines index sites and the preference for a directory blog as opposed to a subdomain blog, I want to implement a permanent redirect so that `example.com/blog/anything` will redirect to `blog.example.com/anything` regardless of how many slashes or parameters the url contains.  So even `example.com/blog/a/b/c/d/e?google=true` should redirect to `blog.example.com/a/b/c/d/e?google=true`

So far the following works if there is only one directory after blog:

```
  get '/blog/:what', to: redirect('http://blog.codeundercover.com/%{what}')
```

I, however, need this to work regardless of what text comes after `/blog`.  How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think this is something I would handle in the rails router.  This is something that should be handled at the server level.

Answer (score 2):

Your route is not using a wildcard route. Instead, it's what the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) refers to as a [Static Segment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments)

You'll want to use [Wildcard Globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) instead:

```
get '/blog/*what', to: redirect('http://blog.codeundercover.com/%{what}'), constraints: { what: /.*/ }
```

Comment: @Philip7899 Try adding a regex constraint.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: @WesFoster, why does the regex constraint help?

Answer (score 0):

```
get "/blog(/*what)", to: redirect("http://blog.codeundercover.com/%{what}")
```